inspect.signature: invalid method signature for lambda in class member
The following code throws a ValueError ('invalid method signature')
import inspect
class Foo:
    boo = lambda: 'baa'
    
print(inspect.signature(Foo().boo))

Why? Changing it to boo = lambda x: 'baa' does not throw an error. It seems like, that python automatically binds the object (class instance) to the lambda function, but this seems strange to me (so lambdas are effectively the same as normal def's?).
When we run the following
import inspect
class Foo:
    boo = lambda x: x
print(Foo().boo())

We get <__main__.Foo object at 0x7dd9a4813dd0>, so it is indeed just binding the object to lambda.
But this does not explain, why inspect.signature fails.

the problem is not about lambdas. This is the def-counterpart which raises the same error: class Foo: def boo(): 'baa'

the main problem is that your boo function is a kind of hybrid type, if applied to a class is a function but when applied to an object is of type bound method. When implemented such functions you should be aware of this fact

The issue occurs because lambdas in a class are treated like methods. When accessed via an instance Foo().boo(), the instance self is automatically passed as the first argument to boo.
inspect.signature fails because the lambda method boo has no parameters, but as a bound method, it expects self as an argument, causing a mismatch.
To avoid automatic instance binding, use staticmethod:
class Foo:
    boo = staticmethod(lambda: 'baa')

print(inspect.signature(Foo.boo))


Lambdas defined in a class are treated as methods, so Python automatically binds the instance (self) when the lambda is accessed through an instance. However, lambdas without parameters (e.g., lambda: 'baa') don’t explicitly declare self, causing inspect.signature to fail with a ValueError because it cannot infer the implicit method signature. Adding an explicit parameter (e.g., lambda self: 'baa') aligns the lambda with the expected method signature and resolves the issue.
Eg
import inspect

class Foo:
    boo = lambda: 'baa'

print(Foo().boo())
print(inspect.signature(Foo().boo))  # Raises ValueError: 'invalid method signature'

class FooFixed:
    boo = lambda self: 'baa'

print(inspect.signature(FooFixed().boo))  # Outputs: (self)


I believe the error was thrown because of the following reasons:

When you define boo as a lambda: 'baa' at the class level, it behaves as a simple class attribute rather than an instance method. Lambdas are anonymous functions and they don't carry the metadata that is required to define a proper method signature. As a result, when inspect.signature tries to analyze the boo method, it fails because lambdas don't provide a full method signature in the context of being a class or instance method.
In Python, methods defined inside a class using def are automatically wrapped into "bound methods" when accessed via an instance. This binding ensures the process receives the instance (self) as its first parameter. Lambdas defined as class attributes skip this behavior entirely, it means they don’t include the self parameter that is needed for instance methods.
The inspect.signature function works with callable objects that follow Python's standards for functions or methods. Lambdas defined as class attributes don't meet all these requirements, that is why inspect.signature cannot analyze them properly.

These documents may be useful:
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda
https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature

Sorry, but all your points are wrong. 1) in general is a bad practice bind a lambda to a variable but it does not mean that it looses its function-like behaviour. inspect will not fail (see also answer of Dmitriy Ivkov) 2) no, see my 2nd comment to the OP 3) which requirement is missing for lambdas? Just, run inspect.signature(lambda x, y: None) and works fine
